# Is it possible to plot a solid area (not line) Radar Chart in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, radar-chart

I am trying to add a new series solid area radar chart in an existing line radar chart of google spreadsheet. Is it possible to do in scripts? Because this types of charts are not seen in the google spreadsheet chart list. The line type radar chart is what I have now. I want a solid area type radar chart as shown in the other sample image.[image: Radar chart]

[image: Expected chart type]

I just used available line radar charts in charts. I'm not very smart in google scripts. But I am expecting a google script or any other possible solution. Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your question, 2 images are shown. What is each image?

Comment: @Tanaike, The line radar is what I have now. The other solid area filled type radar is the expected chart type.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your 2 images, the top image and the bottom image are the input situation and the output situation, respectively. And, you want to convert the top image to the bottom image. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike, There are two series line type in the existing chart. I wanted to convert one series to solid-filled type while the other series stay same as a line. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to test it, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including your current chart?

Comment: @Tanaike, how can I share the sheet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254458/discussion-between-lighthouselk-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Tanaike This is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SCwaLnQHLMp28hGYP0L5gTNKi05XYCIDF6XPeFjUtMg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the chart information and could not really find anything in Apps Script or the Sheets API or advanced sheets service (references below) that resembles the example chart that you shared, I found something named "Area chart" but it seems to correlate with this chart type in spreadsheets:

[image: Sheets chart screenshot]

Here is the reference of all charts available in sheets, Sheets API and Apps script:

- [Spreadsheet chart types](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190718)
- [Apps Script chart types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-type.html)
- [Advanced Sheet service API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#:%7E:text=Union%20field%20chart.%20The%20specific%20chart%20specification%2C%20exactly%20one%20value%20must%20be%20set.%20chart%20can%20be%20only%20one%20of%20the%20following%3A)

There may be some third party options like add ons that you could use but I couldn't find anything specific, if you happen to have Google Workspace you may also try submitting a [Feature Idea](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762) however this is mostly taken as a suggestion and not necessarily a formal request that will definitely be included so please make sure to keep the right expectations with the Feature ideas process.

Comment: Thank you for spending time on the above matter. I also searched in the above places. But still unsuccessful. Thanks again for the ideas.